# How to know where to stop receiving in a UDP connection between multiple nodes

Tags: java, udp, arrays, datagram

I have an app that makes a broadcast and receives message from multiple network nodes(I also wrote these apps, so I can control what and how they send). While receiving this data, I need to separate each node's message, so I can deserialize them to a meaningful Class that I have. Until now, I solved this by keeping every message of every client the same size, 267 bytes. However, this solution is obviously not correct. Another idea i have is to put "\0" at the end of the byte array while sending, so my app can receive datagrams one by one.

Could anyone direct me to the right mindset with this problem ?

Thanks.

Edit: The question was not clear :

```
Udp.receivePacket(bindedPort, byteSize, discoveryTimeout);
```

Here I am receiving message from multiple hosts, almost at the same time. So they are all stacked in the Udp buffer i suppose. I thought in order to receive datagram one by one and prevent ruining the byte order and integrity, I needed to know how much bytes to receive. My question was meant to learn about techniques to do that.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem is. UDP datagrams are already kept separate by the UDP implementation and the implementation will tell you the number of bytes in each datagram you receive.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. But you understood it right. So when I give byte size to receive, does it just tell the receive function the MAX amount to receive ?

Comment: That's correct, it's usually the size of the buffer.

Comment: So, how does java, or any underlying system knows, when the message ends? Is it marked with a NULL character or something like that ?

Comment: UDP datagrams are encapsulated in IP datagrams. The IP protocol specifies how to determine the length of the datagram (through the header fields -- offset, length, and MF bit), and this is passed up to the UDP layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message when transmission is complete send a string "end" and check in server when a string "end" is encountered stop receiving.